# Android Image Annotation Bitmap issue

Tags: android, image, kotlin, canvas, bitmap

I am creating a basic media library and one of the features is image annotation.  I am getting a media file from the android storage system then converting it to a bitmap.  I then create a canvas from the bitmap and use the drawLine function of the canvas class to allow basic annotation.  The problem I am currently having is that the canvas and image or not the same size so the lines are drawn in the wrong location.

This is the code for creating the bitmaps.

```
val bmpFactoryOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
                bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false
                bmp = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(it.mediaUrl)).rotate(270f)

                alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    bmp!!.width, bmp!!
                        .height, bmp!!.config
                )
```

Then I create the canvas, paint and matrix objects.

```
canvas = Canvas(alteredBitmap!!)
paint = Paint()
paint!!.color = Color.GREEN
paint!!.strokeWidth = 5f
matrix = Matrix()
canvas!!.drawBitmap(bmp!!, matrix!!, paint)
```

I then set the alteredBitmap to be the image of an image view

```
annotateIV!!.setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap)
```

The last place an error would make sense is in the touchListener of the imageView.

```
annotateIV!!.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
                    when (motionEvent.action) {
                        ACTION_DOWN -> {
                            downx = motionEvent.x
                            downy = motionEvent.y
                        }
                        ACTION_MOVE -> {
                            upx = motionEvent.x
                            upy = motionEvent.y
                            canvas!!.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint!!)
                            annotateIV!!.invalidate()
                            downx = upx
                            downy = upy
                        }
                        ACTION_UP -> {
                            upx = motionEvent.x
                            upy = motionEvent.y
                            canvas!!.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint!!)
                            annotateIV!!.invalidate()
                        }
                        ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                        }
                        else -> {

                        }
                    }
                    return@setOnTouchListener true
                }
```

I have tried creating the bitmap in different ways but constantly run into the same scaling error.
[Image Example of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq3rh.jpg)
Notice the lines drawn top left.  Those were created when attempting to draw across the whole screen.

Thank you for anyone that has a look and any help is greatly appreciated.

Adjustments made to creation of bitmap.  This causes the image to be zoomed in but lines atleast drawn in correct location

```
bmp = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(it.mediaUrl)).rotate(270f)

                alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    bmp!!.width, bmp!!
                        .height, bmp!!.config
                )
                alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(alteredBitmap!!, annotateIV.width, annotateIV.height, false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Canvas` have size of `Bitmap`, probably way bigger than dimension of your screen. you are setting `Bitmap` to `annotateIV`, which I assume is `ImageView` and have some `scaleType` set up for fitting whole `Bitmap` inside view. this still doesn't actually resize `Bitmap`/`Canvas`, its just a "preview"

for fixing this you should scale your `Bitmap` to size of `ImageView` or make some factor/ratio value of bitmapSize/imageViewSize and multiply all `motionEvent.x` and `motionEvent.y` by it

btw. calling `invalidate()` when every `MotionEvent` arrives isn't efficient way... this is why your line isn't rounded, it's clearly made with straight lines

Comment: alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        annotateIV.width, annotateIV.height, bmp!!.config
                    )   I changed the bitmap creation to this, now the image is very zoomed in but the lines are drawn in the correct area on screen.  Could you clarify what you mean by the last part of your post if possible.  Thank you so much

Comment: about `invalidate()`? you are calling this method with every new `MotionEvent`, but it takes time to draw. every next `invalidate` call during previous running is just ommited as UI hangs on previous operation, thus you are losing some points to draw - this is clearly visible on the bottom part of your green line, its made with few straight lines ("dots connected"), isn't rounded just like your finger move over the screen

Comment: sorry about the bitmap resizing and or using a ratio for the motionEvents.  How would I go about implementing that?  I tried using createScaledBitmap, this resulted in the image being zoomed in but atleast the lines were drawn in the correct place.

Comment: but for the invalidate how often would you recommend having it called?

Comment: load your `Bitmap` as before, but just after that use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` method and scale it to size of `ImageView`. using `Bitmap.createBitmap( annotateIV.width, annotateIV.height,...` you are loading only part of `Bitmap`, which set on `ImageView` looks like zoomed

Comment: 'bmp = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(it.mediaUrl)).rotate(270f)
                    
                    alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        bmp!!.width, bmp!!
                            .height, bmp!!.config
                    )
                    alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(alteredBitmap!!, annotateIV.width, annotateIV.height, true)'

Comment: Apologies for how messed it is, I tried creating a bitmap from the image and then creating a scaled bitmap from that bitmap

Comment: Still gave me the same bug were it is zoomed in

Comment: you've messed your code a bit... you are using `canvas!!.drawBitmap(bmp!!,...`, but also `setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap)` . use only one bitmap - `alteredBitmap`. this `bmp` `Bitmap` is needed only to load bitmap data and create final properly scaled `alteredBitmap` `Bitmap`

Comment: Thank you for the help I got the last bit sorted now, I just had to change which bitmap was drawn to canvas as well